# How to fix Rails console error about ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am implementing a Student class which inherits from a User class using STI in Rails. Each Student is associated with a StudentRecord via a *has_one* association where each StudentRecord *belongs* to a Student.

In the **console**, when I add a StudentRecord via `student.build_student_record` and I call `student.save` I receive an error of the form *"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid..."*. However, when I test this same functionality using `rails test` I receive no errors...

test/models/student_test.rb :

```
class StudentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "create Student with student_record" do
    student = Student.create(
      name:  "Example Student", 
      email: "example@student.org",
      password:              "foobar",
      password_confirmation: "foobar")
    student.build_student_record(student_number: 12345)
    student.save
    student = student.reload
    assert_equal 12345, student.student_record.student_number
  end
end
```

Here is a [photo of the console error](https://imgur.com/a/2T8IsLu), and I have added my other relevant code below.

app/models/user.rb :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
end
```

db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_type_to_users :

```
class AddTypeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :type, :string
  end
end
```

app/models/student.rb :

```
class Student < User
  has_one :student_record
end
```

db/migrate/[timestamp]_create_student_records.rb :

```
class CreateStudentRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :student_records do |t|
      t.integer :student_number
      t.references :student, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/student_record :

```
class StudentRecord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
  validates :student_id, presence: true
  validates :student_number, presence: true
end
```

Comment: show your full code for `User` model

Comment: Try with this. `t.references :student, foreign_key: false`

Comment: @KBIIX Thanks, that worked!!! Any chance you could explain why it still works in that case (and didn't in the other)? I was under the impression that associations should set the foreign_key to true. Is it because Student is inheriting for User?

Comment: You're using STI so there is no `students` table for `t.references :student` to refer to, there is just a `users` table with some STI columns mashed into it to differentiate between plain users and students. Dropping the FK leaves you open to referential integrity issues, might be better to explicitly tell it to reference the `users` table.

Answer (score 1):

KBIIX's solution above appears to fix the error too, however I have ended up changing the line in *db/migrate/[timestamp]_create_student_records.rb* to:

```
t.references :student, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
```

..in case anyone is curious.